# How to set Spark configuration to use TASK nodes on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cluster-computing, amazon-emr

I am not a spark configuration expert and I have an issue with the task nodes. My cluster in AWS has 1 Master, 3 Core and 5 Task nodes. I can see load only on the Master node and on the 3 Core nodes, and the Task nodes are doing nothing.

Instances:

- Core nodes: 4 vCores, 16Gib memory
- Task nodes: 4 vCores, 8Gib memory

My configuration:

```
    .set("spark.executors.cores", "5")\
    .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")\
    .set("spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead", "1024")\
    .set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","108")\
    .set("spark.default.parallelism", "108")\
    .set("spark.yarn.node-labels.enabled","true")\
    .set("spark.yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression", "CORE")\
    .set("spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression","TASK")\
    .set("spark.yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled", "false")\
    .set("spark.yarn.node-labels.configuration-type", 'distributed')\
    .set("spark.memory.fraction", "0.8")\
    .set("spark.memory.storageFraction", "0.2")\
    .set("maximizeResourceAllocation","true")\
```

Is there any option in the configuration to solve this issue?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=662964. We are planing to use this functionality also. So, please post if you manage. Thanks

Comment: They have always just worked for me w/ EMR. Keep in mind that some operations can only be done by the driver (before it the workload of a job is distributed)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there is separate node level called `TASK`.

TASK is part of default node level. If you see in my cluster, I have 10 TASK node running but it is part of default partition. So remove the property `.set("spark.yarn.executor.nodeLabelExpression","TASK")`

[image: YARN node levels]

Also can you add this in your spark config:

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
```

Also I don’t think you need to specify these 2 property.
In yarn-site.xml its already configured.
`.set("spark.yarn.node-labels.enabled","true")\
 .set("spark.yarn.node-labels.am.default-node-label-expression", "CORE")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried with the  `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`, but there is no change..